# Sql query to solve

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql table like this one:

```
id  email           links
1   test1@test.com  www.link1.com
2   test2@test.com  www.link2.com
3   test3@test.com  www.link3.com
4   test1@test.com  www.link4.com
5   test2@test.com  www.link5.com
6   test2@test.com  www.link6.com
7   test4@test.com  www.link7.com
8   test5@test.com  www.link8.com
9   test6@test.com  www.llink9.com
10  test2@test.com  www.link10.com
```

And I need to find a query that will give this kind of result:

```
email                link1          link2          link3          link4
test1@zendata.ca     www.link1.com  www.link4.com
test2@zendata.ca     www.link2.com  www.link5.com  www.link6.com  www.link10.com
test3@zendata.ca     www.link3.com
test4@zendata.ca     www.link7.com
test5@zendata.ca     www.link8.com
test6@zendata.ca     www.llink9.com
```

Unique emails with each of the associated links...

Thank you if you can solve this problem,

Comment: Can you give us a little more information on what you're doing with the data? For example do you have a scripting language that you're working with?

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of links in advance?

Comment: Someone said in a post last week that this is a Pivot Table feature.

Comment: well, you can't in raw SQL unless you know how many links you have. And what client language too?

Comment: @jp2code: no, it isn't a PIVOT table. That requires fixed columns

Comment: It may be correct to call it a dynamic pivot (or dynamic crosstab): http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#Crosstab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much more easily done with `GROUP_CONCAT()` and then processed in application code to split up the resultant string:

```
SELECT email, GROUP_CONCAT(links) AS link_list FROM tbl GROUP BY email
```

Example results:

```
email                link_list
--------------------------------------
test1@zendata.ca     www.link1.com,www.link4.com
test2@zendata.ca     www.link2.com,www.link5.com,www.link6.com,www.link10.com
```

This assumes, of course, that you will be processing this result set with *some* application code in some other programming language.

Comment: What if the links contain `,` characters?

Comment: @Emil Vikström use the SEPARATOR clause http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: @EmilVikström You can use an alternate separator like `|` which doesn't appear in your result set. See docs linked in another comment.

Comment: I'm aware of that parameter, but how do you select the correct separator? You'll need a separator that's guaranteed to not appear in any of the links. My main point is that you should not play with the atomicity of the database and it's results in this manner. Instead, solve this in application code. It's just as efficient to fetch multiple rows for each e-mail address into your application code as it is to concatenate and then split the string, but concatenation have multiple caveats you have to consider.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible if you want to maintain atomicity (one data atom in each field). Try to not confuse the database schema (columns and tables) with it's data (rows).

You can, however, sort the rows according to email and in that way make it easy to fetch the data in correct order in your application code. Here's a simple example in PHP, where I don't even have to sort the result beforehand (an "array" in PHP is actually a hashmap):

```
$linksForEmail = array();
$resultset = mysql_query('SELECT email, links FROM table;');
while ($a = mysql_fetch_array($resultset, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  list($email, $link) = $a;
  if (!isset($linksForEmail[$email])
    $linksForEmail[$email] = array();

  //Add to the array
  $linksForEmail[$email][] = $link;
}
```

*The parentheses above are somewhat simplified definitions of "data" and "schema", but still: don't confuse those two concepts*

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't many different links, you can do something like this

```
select 
email,
max(case when links = 'link1' then links else '' end) as link1,
max(case when links = 'link2' then links else '' end) as link2,
max(case when links = 'link3' then links else '' end) as link3,
max(case when links = 'link4' then links else '' end) as link4
from table
group by email
```